# creating a function for getsymbols

Tags: r, function, yahoo-finance, stock

I am trying to create a function that will take a stock in as an input and return me the stock price data from yahoo finance using getSymbols but when I tried to use the function I got this error " Error in `[.xts`(Symbols, Symbols == x) : 'i' or 'j' out of range"

this is the code

```
library(quantmod) 
pelumi=function(stock){
  stock.e=getSymbols(stock , auto.assign = T)
  ty=as.data.frame(stock.e)
  return(ty)
}
```

Comment: This is a very simple problem. You have to pass a string to your function. getSymbols() only takes a string or vector of strings as the argument. Try typing getSymbols(SPY)  and you will get the same error. You have to pass a string. getSymbols("SPY")

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already using `quantmod` why not just use `getQuote`?

For example, to get Apple's stock price from Yahoo:

```
library(quantmod)
getQuote("AAPL", src = "yahoo")
```

Comment: no this is a theoretical function that I am creating . I want to know why the function named pelumi is giving me this error :" Error in [.xts(Symbols, Symbols == x) : 'i' or 'j' out of range"

Comment: What are you imputing?  When I try `pelumi("AAPL")` I get:
  `stock.e
1    AAPL` and no error

Comment: @Greg your too easy on him lol, he should have figured this one out on his own. Pretty simple problem if you ask me. His problem was, he was not calling a string in his function.

Answer (score 0):

```
stock = c('CA.PA','^FCHI','BN.PA','BNP.PA','RNO.PA')
stockData <- new.env() 


rec_data <-
  function(stock) {
    getSymbols(
      stock,
      env = stockData,
      src = "yahoo",
      auto.assign = TRUE,
      warnings = FALSE
      )
    rs <- na.omit(stock)
    return(rs)
  }
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. You can use the [edit] button to improve this answer to get more votes and reputation!

Answer (score 0):

The main issue in your code is because you are setting `auto.assign = T`. This means that the result will be loaded into `parent.frame()`. Look at the help file for `getSymbols` by typing `?getSymbols`. You need to set `auto.assign` as `FALSE` to return a result inside your function. Here is the code:

```
> library(quantmod) 
> pelumi=function(stock){
+   stock.e=getSymbols(stock , auto.assign = FALSE)
+   ty=as.data.frame(stock.e)
+   return(ty)
+ }
> pelumi("IBM")
           IBM.Open IBM.High IBM.Low IBM.Close IBM.Volume IBM.Adjusted
2007-01-03    97.18    98.40   96.26     97.27    9196800     66.10009
2007-01-04    97.25    98.79   96.88     98.31   10524500     66.80686
2007-01-05    97.60    97.95   96.91     97.42    7221300     66.20204
2007-01-08    98.50    99.50   98.35     98.90   10340000     67.20779
2007-01-09    99.08   100.33   99.07    100.07   11108200     68.00288
2007-01-10    98.50    99.05   97.93     98.89    8744800     67.20101
...
```